# Connect two different databases with single ADO connection using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, ado, vba

The source file is an excel file (Sheet1) and the target file is a database (oracle sql developer). My requirement is to compare both the databases and verify whether all the records are matching and do some more logical comparisons between them. So I have copied the records from target database (sql developer) and stored it in the Sheet2 of source file (excel). I wrote a vbscript to connect Excel file using adodb connection strings and written the sql query to compare the records using the join query.

**Sample Query:**

```
SELECT srcTbl.Column_SH1_A, trgtTbl.Column_SH2_A, srcTbl.Column_SH1_B,
       trgtTbl.Column_SH2_B 
  FROM [Sheet1$] srcTbl, [Sheet2$] trgtTbl 
 WHERE srcTbl.Column_SH1_A = trgtTbl.Column_SH2_A 
   AND (srcTbl.Column_SH1_B <> trgtTbl.Column_SH2_B)
```

Using the above procedure I can able to compare the records from different databases, but I don't want to move the records from target database to source file (Sheet2 in excel), instead I want to connect Excel file as one connection, SQL developer as another connection and directly use both the databases in the above join query (instead of Sheet1 and Sheet2, I want to use Excel database and SQL Developer database).

Is it possible? If not can you please recommend any other solution.

Comment: You can't join Excel to Oracle in a regular `SELECT .. JOIN` in PLSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to do the opposite, read the Excel file into another SQL Developer database table, preferably in the same schema as the other table and perform your sql in your script or database management tool. It is not possible to use different connection parameters like eg the provider in one connectionstring.

Comment: Yaa thats better for large databases, but I wanted to merge the connections as said above, and it seems its not possible. Thanks for your replies :)

Comment: there are many approaches possible but not that one, could you accept the answer then ?